# Recursively list all resource tags within Azure Resource Groups

Tags: azure, tags, azure-powershell, azure-cli, azureportal

We have a large number of Azure Subscriptions which currently run into the hundreds.

I'm looking to generate a report (ideally using Azure Powershell or Azure CLI) to recursively extract a list of all tags assigned to every single resource within every resource group, for between 40-50 of the subscriptions.

Currently, I can list all tags assigned at Resource Group level, but I simply can't find a way to list the tags assigned to the individual resources within each Resource Group. The list of subscriptions and resource groups on which I'd like to extract this report, are saved in a CSV file which includes two columns displaying the Subscription name and Resource Group respectively.

Any tips on how to achieve the above would be fantastic and most appreciated.

Comment: how about list the `azure sources` from the `resource group` first, then list tags for `each azure resource`?

Comment: @IvanYang, are you suggesting using the portal.........or the use of a script for this?

Comment: of course scripts:), there are related `az powershell commands` like [Get-AzResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azresource?view=azps-5.8.0) you can use to list azure resources from a resource group:).

Comment: @IvanYang, yes, already started looking into that. Will provide some feedback in due course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not detailed code but the idea here.

1.You should write a loop, in the loop, change the `subscription` each time by using this cmdlet:

`Set-AzContext -Subscription $subscription_name`.

2.Then get all the `resource group` in the specified `subscription` by using this cmdlet:

```
$resource_groups = Get-AzResourceGroup
```

3.Then write a nested loop(loop for each `resource group`), in this nested loop, use this cmdlet to get all `azure resources` within a `resource group`:

```
foreach($rg in $resource_groups){
   $azure_resources = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $rg.ResourceGroupName
}
```

4.Write another nested loop in step 3, this loop is used to go though all the `azure resources` within the specified `resource group`. Then use the code below to fetch tags for each `azure resource` within the `resource group`:

```
foreach($r in $azure_resources){
     #the following code can get all the tags for one resource
     $r.tags

}
```

Comment: that's great. Will give that a go and provide some feedback shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Ivan Yang's logic. I have built the PowerShell Script;

#---------DECLARE VARIABLES------------------------------------#

```
$bnsSubscription = Get-AzSubscription
$day = Get-Date -Format " ddMMMyyyy"
$tagPath = "C:\mytempfolder\"+"$day-Tag-Details.csv"
$tagFolderPath = "C:\mytempfolder\"
```

#---------DECLARE VARIABLES------------------------------------#

```
function Get-ResourceTag {

    foreach ($subs in $bnsSubscription) {
        Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $subs.Name | Out-Null 
        Write-Host 'The selected Subscription is' ($subs).Name
        New-Item -ItemType file -Path "$tagFolderPath\$($subs.Name).csv" -Force
        $resource_groups = Get-AzResourceGroup
        $resource_groups_details = Get-AzResourceGroup | Sort-Location ResourceGroupName | Format-Table -GroupBy Location ResourceGroupName,ProvisioningState,Tags
        Write-Host 'The selected Resource Group is' ($resource_groups).Name 'and the tag information as follows'
        #$resource_groups_details
        $resource_groups | Select-Object ResourceGroupName,Tags | Export-CSV -Path "$tagFolderPath\$($subs.Name).csv"  -Append


        $OutputFile = @()
        foreach($rg in $resource_groups){
            $azure_resources = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $rg.ResourceGroupName

            $TestTags = $Resource.Tags.GetEnumerator()

            foreach($r in $azure_resources){

                Write-Host 'The selected resource is' ($r).Name 'and the information as follows'
                
                $RGHT = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]"
                $RGHT.Add("RGName",$r.ResourceGroupName)
                $RGHT.Add("ResourceName",$r.name)
                $RGHT.Add("Location",$r.Location)
                $RGHT.Add("Id",$r.ResourceId)
                $RGHT.Add("ResourceType",$r.ResourceType)
                $RGHT.Add("ResourceTags",$r.Tags)

                $OutputFile += New-Object psobject -Property $RGHT

                $OutputFile | Export-Csv -Path "C:\mytempfolder\test22.csv" -append -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -Force

           
            }
        }
    }

    
}
```

#---------CALL FUNCTION------------------------------------#

```
Get-ResourceTag
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: @vijay borkar does that above script works?